# Summation iterated over a variable length

Tags: sum, pyomo

I have written an optimization problem in pyomo and need a constraint, which contains a summation that has a variable length:
u_i_t[i, t]*T_min_run - sum (tnewnew in (t-T_min_run+1)..t-1) u_i_t[i,tnewnew] <= sum (tnew in t..(t+T_min_run-1)) u_i_t[i,tnew]

T is my actual timeline and N my machines
usually I iterate over t, but I need to guarantee the machines are turned on for certain amount of time.

```
def HP_on_rule(model, i, t):
    return model.u_i_t[i, t]*T_min_run - sum(model.u_i_t[i, tnewnew] for tnewnew in range((t-T_min_run+1), (t-1))) <= sum(model.u_i_t[i, tnew] for tnew in range(t, (t+T_min_run-1)))
model.HP_on_rule = Constraint(N, rule=HP_on_rule)
```

I hope you can provide me with the correct formulation in pyomo/python.

The problem is that t is a running variable and I do not know how to implement this in Python. tnew is only a help variable. E.g. t=6 (variable), T_min_run=3 (constant) and u_i_t is binary [00001111100000...] then I get:
1*3 - 1 <= 3
As I said, I do not know how to implement this in my code and the current version is not running.
TypeError: HP_on_rule() missing 1 required positional argument: 't'

Comment: What is the problem on your constraint? Please be more clear.

Comment: I have specified my problem.

Comment: Can you show us what is the `def HP_on_rule():` line? The one that should come right before the `return ...` line.

Comment: I have added the line.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you didn't provide all your arguments to the function rule.

Since `t` is a parameter of your function, I assume that it corresponds to an element of set `T` (your timeline).

Then, your last line of your code example should include not only the set `N`, but also the set `T`. Try this:

```
model.HP_on_rule = Constraint(N, T, rule=HP_on_rule)
```

Please note: Building a `Constraint` with a "for each" part, you must provide the Pyomo `Set`s that you want to iterate over at the begining of the call for `Constraint` construction. As a rule of thumb, your constraint rule function should have 1 more argument than the number of Pyomo `Set`s specified in the `Constraint` initilization line.

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work. I think the Problem is that I have a variable range over the summation and pyomo only accepts ranges for the summation as constants.

Comment: Perhaps, you could provide the error that you get? However, if it is what I think, it's not a valid formulation to base your summation range on a model variable, since it must be static. And that's not only Pyomo. It's like the equivalent of putting a `if` that includes variables in a constraint, it will not work and is no valid mathematical formulation. You should work on your model. Have you tried using binary variables? That's what we use instead of that kind of things in a model.

Comment: Note: I believe that model variables and code variables are two separated things. In my answer, I was referring to code variables. In my comment, I am talking about model variables.